# It's ok to import all action creators in all container components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Right know I have a index file where I import different files with action creators for different views:

```
import generalActions from './generalActions'
import vftActions from './vftActions'
import shareActions from './shareActions'
import codeFormActions from './codeFormActions'
import signupActions from './signupActions'

const actions = {
    ...generalActions,
    ...vftActions,
    ...shareActions,
    ...codeFormActions,
    ...signupActions
}

export default actions
```

And then I import the actions index every time with all the actions:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import actions from '../../redux/actions'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContainerComponent)
```

Its ok if I separate this in different exports and import only the action creators that my container needs?

Also with this it's very probable that when I have a lot of action creators it will be difficult to find names that are not taken.

What do you think it's the best aproach?

Answer (score 12):

I think the better solution is to export every action module separately.
I use next architecture in my projects:

The index file for all actions `actions/index.js`:

```
// just import actions from other files (modules)
import * as notification from './notification'
import * as friend from './friend'
import * as profile from './profile'

// export all actions as modules
export { notification }
export { friend }
export { profile }
```

After that, in my Container I import only what I need from `actions/index.js`:

```
import { notification,
         profile } from '../actions'
```

With this approach, you will get full control of what actions do you need for your Containers.

Answer (score 2):

Importing only actions that you need is a common way to do that. I don't understand why do you need to bundle all actions in one object.

You can also use namespaced import like this:

```
import * as generalActions from './generalActions'
```

in this case, you don't need to `export default` action object containing all `generalActions` you can just `export` each action.

Generally, it's a good practice to import only what you actually use.

Comment: "Generally, it's a good practice to import only what you actually use."
Why is that? This is exactly the question being asked, so elaborating on theses good practices would be helpful :-)